# Update win10 to win11 using Assistant with a script

Tags: string, automation, windows-11, windows-update

I have a 100 + computers which hardware is supported for win11 and I want to use a script and I've been trying to update windows 10 to windows 11. I tried to use the heresjaken script "https://heresjaken.com/install-windows-10-upgrade-through-powershell-using-windows-update-assistant/" with small modification by updating a new win11update assistant but what happens after running the script it stuck at EULA. Tried different strings in arguments but it's not accepting it. Little help would be appreciateable. Thank you.

The below code function is to download the windows 11 assistant and run it in silently but in the argument it doesn't accept the EULA. The Arguments doesn't seem to be working for Win11 update assistant. Need Help!

```
    try {
# Declarations
[string]$DownloadDir = 'C:\Temp\Windows_FU\packages'
[string]$LogDir = 'C:\Temp\Logs'
[string]$LogFilePath = [string]::Format("{0}\{1}_{2}.log", $LogDir, "$(get-date -format `"yyyyMMdd_hhmmsstt`")", $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name.Replace(".ps1", ""))
[string]$Url = 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2171764'
[string]$UpdaterBinary = "$($DownloadDir)\Windows11InstallationAssistant.exe"
[string]$UpdaterArguments = '/eula=1 /auto upgrade /copylogs $LogDir'
[System.Net.WebClient]$webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I used process explorer to look over the available arguments because the set of arguments I used for other upgrader tools in the past weren't working. I haven't found allot of documentation on scripting with the windows 11 upgrader tool online.

After trying a couple of combinations this set of arguments worked for me:

```
'/Install  /MinimizeToTaskBar /QuietInstall /SkipEULA /copylogs $LogDir'
```